# How to loop and calculate aggregate metric in python

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, apache-spark

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| ID | Date | agecat | weightcat | JOB | YesNO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202101 | 20-30 | 4 | plumber | 1 |
| 2 | 202101 | 30-40 | 5 | painter | 0 |

and so on, with many months, about 7 age categories, 10 weightcategories, and 10 jobs.

I want to calculate the count of the Yesses (=1) divided by the count of Yes and no (1 or 0).
And this for every subsegment. meaning I end up with #of months * 7 (agecat) * 10 (weightcat) * 10  (jobs) different aggregated metrics.

Kind regards.

Comment: Check Pandas documentation for groupby. Number of Yes will be the sum of the "YesNO" columns. Count will be the total. Then do the math.https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html

Comment: @wokter did the proposed answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

#### Approach 1

You may use spark sql by creating a temporary view of your dataframe `df`

```py
df.createOrReplaceTempView('my_data')
```

then running the following sql query

```py
results_df = sparkSession.sql("""
SELECT
    Date,
    agecat,
    weightcat,
    JOB,
    SUM(YesNo)/COUNT(YesNo) as my_metric
FROM
   my_data
GROUP BY
    Date,
    agecat,
    weightcat,
    JOB
""")
```

or

#### Approach 2

using the pyspark api

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

results_df = df.groupBy(
    F.col("Date"),
    F.col("agecat"),
    F.col("weightcat"),
    F.col("JOB"),
).agg(
    F.lit(F.sum("YesNO")/F.count("YesNO")).alias("my_metric")
)
```

#### Output

```py
results_df.show()
```

```
+------+------+---------+-------+---------+
|  Date|agecat|weightcat|    JOB|my_metric|
+------+------+---------+-------+---------+
|202101| 20-30|        4|plumber|      1.0|
|202101| 30-40|        5|painter|      0.0|
+------+------+---------+-------+---------+
```